# How to integrate Grunt with project from eclipse.

Tags: gruntjs

I am new to use grunt, please give the steps to integrate the grunt with dynamic web project (webcontent).

Comment: I suggest you use command line, very easy. create you gruntfile.js and be happy

Comment: can you please give the sample structure

Comment: I answered bellow for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I will try to help you.

create a file called **Gruntfile.js** in the root of your project:

change the path according to your project.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var config = {};

    //src ===============================
    var src;
    config.src = src = {
        sassMain: 'scss/main.scss',
        distFolder: 'public/stylesheets/app.dist.css',
        devFolder: 'public/stylesheets/app.dev.css',
        sassFolder: 'scss/**/*.scss',
        serverPort: 8000
    };


    //Concat ===============================

    var concat
    config.concat = concat = {};

    concat.dev = {
        files: {
            "public/myapp.development.js": [
                "with-bootstrap/public/js/vendor", "with-bootstrap/public/js/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    };

    //Watch ===============================
    config.watch = {
        scripts: {
            files: ["<%= src.sassFolder %>"],
            tasks: ["sass:dist"]
        }
    }

    //Sass ===============================
    var sass;
    config.sass = sass = {};

    //distribution
    sass.dist = {
        options: {
            style: "compressed",
            noCache: true,
            sourcemap: 'none',
            update: true
        },
        files: {
            "<%= src.distFolder %>": "<%= src.sassMain %>"
        }
    };

    //development env.
    sass.dev = {
        options: {
            style: "expanded",
            lineNumber: true,
        },
        files: {
            "<%= src.devFolder %>": "<%= src.sassMain %>"
        }
    };


    //grunt serve ===============================
    config.connect = {
        server: {
            options: {
                livereload: true,
                port: "<%= src.serverPort %>"
            }
        }
    };


    //Register custom tasks ===============================
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['dev']);
    grunt.registerTask('dev', ['concat:dev', 'sass:dev']);
    grunt.registerTask('dist', ['concat:dev', 'sass:dist']);
    grunt.registerTask('serve', ['connect:server', 'watch']);
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt, {
        scope: 'devDependencies'
    });



    //General setup ===============================
    grunt.initConfig(config);

};
```

in the root of your project run: `npm init` fill out with the info of your project.

after this open the **package.json** file, we are now will include the grunt tasks to be installed.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "*",
    "grunt-exec": "^1.0.1",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.0",
    "time-grunt": "^1.3.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  }
```

run `npm install` to install the grunt tasks and npm dependencies.

be aware you need have installed in your computer grunt and npm.

anyway let me know if that helped you.

good luck

Comment: Thanks Raduken, Its helped for me. If I give full path for file its working fine like 
  config.watch = {
        scripts: {
            files: 'D:/PROJ/Webcontent/App/view/mypage.html',
            tasks: ["sass:dist"]
        }
    }

How can I give full project path for files
like for all js, html and css file

Comment: on my understanding you don't need give path like D:/PROJ....., example your gruntfile.js will be inside D:/PROJ , so you need see where is your js and css to config.